# device.getModel() is not working properly

Tags: react-native, react-native-device-info

> I am trying to get the modelname using DeviceInfo.getModel() the inbuilt method that is provided by the react-native-device-info but for each model instead of giving the model name it is returning iPhone.I am not able to understand why this is happening.
>
> > here is the code that I am using
> >
> > ```
> > console.log(DeviceInfo.getModel());
> > ```

note that the version of react-native and react-native-device-info are respectively 0.53 and 0.12.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> iOS warning: The list with device names is maintained by the community and could lag new devices. It is recommended to use getDeviceId() since it's more reliable and always up-to-date with new iOS devices. We do accept pull requests that add new iOS devices to the list with device names.

Kindly take a note of it!

Answer (score 1):

Right now I am using getDeviceName() to get the string which indicates the device model.

As example if I am using iPhone 11 then getDeviceName() is going to return 'iPhone 11'

Comment: `getDeviceName()` returns name that can be altered by the user, it can be "Filip's iPhone" or anything else.